# Как сделать чтоб когда ты нажимал на кнопку то проигрывалось аудио

Tags: javascript, html

```
<button onmousedown="sound1.play()" class="btn">Нажми</button>
    <script>
        var sound1 = new Audio();<br />
        sound1.src = "zwyk(2).mp3"<br />
    </script></p>
```

Я написал такой код и добавил сам звук на страницу, но звук все равно не проигрывается

Comment: Это SO на русском. Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Уберите из js-кода html-теги **br /**, других проблем там нет.